# How to pass arguments to WinRM plugin (PowerShell) hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, winrm

I'm working on PowerShell snap-in, I plan to host it on IIS as plugin of WSMan module. I'm wondering how to pass additional parameters from web.config to snap-in?

Here details:

Web.config file of application which host PS snap-in:

```
<system.webServer>
    <system.management.wsmanagement.config>
      <PluginModules>
        <OperationsPlugins>
          <Plugin Name="MyPSPlugin" Filename="%windir%\system32\pwrshplugin.dll" SDKVersion="1" XmlRenderingType="text">
            <InitializationParameters>

              <!-- I'd like to declare additional parameter for PS span-in here something like this: -->
              <Param Name="myData" Value="Test" />

              <Param Name="PSVersion" Value="2.0" />
              <Param Name="assemblyname" Value="C:\MyServices\PowerShell\Bin\MyPSSnapin.dll" />
              <Param Name="pssessionconfigurationtypename" Value="MyCompany.PowerShell.MyPSSessionConfiguration" />
            </InitializationParameters>
            <Resources>
              <Resource ResourceUri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Hosting.PowerShell" SupportsOptions="true">
                <Capability Type="Shell" />
              </Resource>
            </Resources>
          </Plugin>
        </OperationsPlugins>
      </PluginModules>
    </system.management.wsmanagement.config>
</system.webServer>
```

Here implementation of PSSessionConfiguration:

```
namespace MyCompany.PowerShell
{
    public class MyPSSessionConfiguration : PSSessionConfiguration
    {    
        public override InitialSessionState GetInitialSessionState(PSSenderInfo senderInfo)
        {
            // read additional parameter something like this:
            var myData = sendrerInfo.ApplicationArguments["myData"];

            return base.GetInitialSessionState(senderInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with powershell plugin development but in web development I add a reference to System.Configuration and then use the ConfigurationManager to read in the settings from the appsettings section of the web.config into a static class with readonly properties. This prevents repeated reading from the web.config by caching the values. Can you apply this same technique?

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="MyData" value="Test"/>
        </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

static class

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
namespace WebTest
{
    public static class CachedSettings
    {
        public static string MyData;
        public static CachedSettings()
        {
            MyData = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyData"];
        }
    }
}
```

I can then easily call it with

```
string a = CachedSettings.MyData;
```

Comment: same approach is already used - there is configuration file for PS Snap-In (MyPSSnapin.dll.config). But, I have to remove the configuration file and pass data through ApplicationArguments.